# Generic DataRow extension

Tags: c#, datarow

I use a extension method to check a DataRowField for null

```
public static string GetValue(this System.Data.DataRow Row, string Column)
{
    if (Row[Column] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return Row[Column].ToString();
    }
}
```

Now I wonder if i could make this more generic. In my case the return type is always string but the Column could also be Int32 or DateTime

Something like

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this System.Data.DataRow Row, string Column, type Type)
```

Comment: Why do you want to return string if it's an int or DateTime? Use the [`DataRowExtensions.Field`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field(v=vs.110).aspx) which is strongly typed and even supports nullable types.

Comment: Return an 'object' instead of string. Also change following : if ((object)Row[Column] == DBNull.Value).  Then you don't have to return cast cell value to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static T value<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName, T defaultValue = default(T)) 
    => row[columnName] is T t ? t : defaultValue;
```

or for earlier C# versions:

```
public static T value<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    object o = row[columnName];
    if (o is T) return (T)o; 
    return defaultValue;
}
```

and sample uses (the underlying type has to match exactly as there is no conversion):

```
int i0 = dr.value<int>("col");       // i0 = 0 if the underlying type is not int

int i1 = dr.value("col", -1);        // i1 = -1 if the underlying type is not int
```

---

Other alternatives without extension can be nullable types:

```
string s = dr["col"] as string;      // s = null if the underlying type is not string 

int? i = dr["col"] as int?;          // i = null if the underlying type is not int

int i1 = dr["col"] as int? ?? -1;    // i = -1 if the underlying type is not int
```

The column name lookup is slower if the case doesn't match, [because a faster case sensitive lookup is attempted first before the slower case insensitive search](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumnCollection.cs,fac5880f93894783).

Comment: If one needs a more robust way, the `Convert.ChangeType` might be used instead of a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Signature of your method will be as follows

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this System.Data.DataRow Row, string Column)
```

In Else part just change the following

```
return (T)Row[Column];
```