# Getting int value from DataRow without converting to string

Tags: c#, ado.net, type-conversion

I have a database field as int.
When I try this:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(row["Int_Field_Name"].ToString());
```

it works.

But this looks very bad and ineffective.

I tried these:

```
int val = row.Field<int>("Int_Field_Name");
int val = (int)row["Int_Field_Name"];
```

But they throw an exception:
***Specified cast is not valid***

Is there a more elegant and more effective way ?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(row["Int_Field_Name"])` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "But this looks very bad and ineffective."?

Comment: I mean that it doesnt make any sense to convert it to string first, and it looks messy.

Comment: what is the type of actual data stored? string? int? or some custom datatype?

Comment: How about using a Typed DataTable?

Comment: check this link for understandable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608801/difference-between-convert-toint32-and-int

Comment: you can create generic function like here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723298/generic-datarow-extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that most of ADO classes like `DataTable` are weakly-typed, so all you can directly extract from them is `object`. The reason is that the underlying providers decide what the data type will be. For example when your underlying data is coming from some database, what you expect to be an `int`, can actually be a `short`, `uint`, `ulong` or `long`, or even `DBNull.Value` value. Hence you need using the `Convert.To*` method family to be completely safe.

But one thing you don't have to do in most cases is calling `ToString`. The conversion functions will nicely convert the values if they are convertible. By convertible I mean they will fail for example if you try to convert a `long` value larger than `int.MaxValue` to `int`.

So your best bet is using

```
Convert.ToInt32(row["Int_Field_Name"])
```

If you feel this ugly (I do a bit too), you can introduce extension methods, like

```
public static int GetInt(this DataRow row, string fieldName) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(row[fieldName]);
}
```

and use it like `myRow.GetInt("Int_Field_Name")`. Of course you can make this extension more robust by some checks and possibly with a fallback value, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
 int q = Convert.ToInt32(row["Int_Field_Name"]);
```

there is also ToInt16 and 64, depend what you need